# How to Debug .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Windows UI

Tags: maui-blazor

I am basically from web background and trying out .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid.
I am running into errors during development with .NET MAUI Window, but not sure how to debug it?
I have looked around all type of windows and cannot find error details anywhere.

I tried debugging, but that is a headspin as it goes into a loop.

[image]

Comment: For some reason F12 tool was not working, but seems like i can see all the error details now

Answer (score 11):

You have to ensure that the WebDev Tools are activated. [Browser developer tools with .NET MAUI Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=windows)

Ensure the Blazor Hybrid project is configured to support browser developer tools. You can confirm developer tools support by searching the app for
**AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools**

If the project isn't already configured for browser developer tools, add support by:

1. Locating where the call to **AddMauiBlazorWebView** is made, likely within the app's **MauiProgram.cs** file.
2. After the call to **AddMauiBlazorWebView**, add the following code:

   ```
   #if DEBUG
       builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
   #endif
   ```

To use browser developer tools with a Windows app:

1. Run the .NET MAUI Blazor app for Windows and navigate to an app page that uses a **BlazorWebView**.
2. Use the keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+I** to open browser developer tools.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-I for inspect, so simple and useful thanks!

Answer (score 11):

There is a way to "remotely inspect" your app using the browser developer tool (F12). First, check if you added the `builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();` in your `MauiProgram.cs`
Run your App and open a new tab in your browser (outside the emulator) and type:

- For Chrome: chrome://inspect
- For Edge: edge://inspect
- For Firefox: about:debugging

Wait a little and you will see an "inspect" button like below:
[image]

And you can even navigate in your App from there:
[image]

Comment: For iOS on mac try Safari following the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=ios